# progress-bar.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: stepNavigator.setHash is not a function magento 2 custom theme

Tags: magento2, checkout-page

> I am facing one issue due to this error in checkout page means
>   shipping rates are not showing properly.

```
progress-bar.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: stepNavigator.setHash is not a function
        at UiClass.initialize (progress-bar.js:31)
        at UiClass.initialize (wrapper.js:109)
        at new UiClass (class.js:49)
        at Object.initComponent (layout.js:137)
        at fire (jquery.js:3232)
        at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3362)
        at Object.deferred.(/project/checkout/anonymous function) (url/project/pub/static/version1544010067/frontend/project/project/en_GB/jquery.js:3461:37)
        at fire (jquery.js:3232)
        at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3362)
        at Object.deferred.(/project/checkout/anonymous function) [as resolve] (url/project/pub/static/version1544010067/frontend/project/project/en_GB/jquery.js:3461:37)
```

Comment: I upgraded from 2.2.4 to 2.3.5 and I am facing the stepNavigator error.